# Why Default MVC Application creating Default pool size of around 2.4 MB?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a sample asp.net application with dot net 4.5.This application is just for testing and there is no logic.Just a simple "Home" & "Account" Controller.
I simply load the application and its application pool size shows "**208412"** Private bytes which is approximately **208.4MB**?
Shared hosting usually have a pool limit of around 100-200 MB.

1. Why MVC creating such a bigger application pool with no logic at
   all?
2. Is not that quite a large memory consumption with blank application?

---

Please correct me if am wrong.Thanks in advance.